# Visual Studio 2015 freezing when trying to publish an asp.net web to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, web-deployment

I created an ASP.NET MVC 5 app and am trying to publish it to Azure (I have an  active subscription). When I right-click the project and choose "Publish to Azure" the modal "Create App Service" shows up and just freezes. I have to kill visual studio process to close it.

[image]

I've tried it in several VM's, some Windows Server 2012 and some Windows 10, from both my office network and home, so I would safely assume it's not an issue with a particular environment but rather a larger issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using.

Comment: @Bernie - Azure SDK 2.8.1

Comment: I tried mine and didn't lock up. A long shot. Try creating at least one resource group in the azure portal first. When I go through the wizard it pre-populates a resource group for me.

Comment: @Bernie - I think that was it. I created a web site in Azure and now I can choose it from that modal window. If you make it into an answer I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Visual Studio 2015 tooling currently (Azure SDK 2.8.1) requires at least one Resource Group to be created.

You can work around this by creating a resource group in the subscription you are using through the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com).

I have opened an issue on the project GitHub site. See [issue #1704](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/1704).

Hope that helps.

Comment: That was the exact issue. Once I created a Resource Group it started working fine.

Comment: @JoãoPereira If you are targeting the same subscription that has a resource group then it might be worth logging an issue on GitHub.

Comment: @JoãoPereira for reference, what version of the SDK are you using? This was originally for version 2.8.1 of the SDK, which is quite old now.

Answer (score 2):

I had to update the Azure tooling via the Visual Studio "Extensions and Updates" menu.  None of these workarounds that involved creating items via the web interface worked or were necessary.